# Java- If else logic

Tags: java, if-statement

I want to make it so that you cannot withdraw less that £0 from my savingAccount.Currently, I am using this method to control what happens:

```
//withdraw money if balance will = less than 0 after withdraw
  public void withdraw(double amount){
     if(balance>0){
      balance= balance-amount;
      updatebalance();
    }else{
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Insufficient funds", "Error",    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
 }
```

This logic works to an extent if the balance is already £0, **but if the balance is greater that 0 it allows you to withdraw money into an overdraft**.

I understand my problem but I dont really understand how I can fix it. I have tried searching online on other forums but I dont really know how to word it into a search... I appreciate any feedback and help I get.

**TLDR: Make my IF statement not allow you to go under £0.**

Thanks

Comment: `if(balance>=amount){`

Comment: Mark, can you post your comment as an answer so I can give you the credit you deserve. Thanks for helping

Comment: @Tom it's not really constructive to be condescending...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple as comparing the existing balance with the requested amount, not zero.

```
if( balance >= amount ){
```